# kubernetes ingress controller redirect

Tags: kubernetes

Our company has a k8s cluster using kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb

It services many different hostnames with the same code.  We have wannabe hackers poking at it via the IP addresses of the load balancer, which all result in a 302 redirect to another server, since there's no hostname to use to determine the configuration.

We'd like to switch on a regex of the hostname not being an IP address in the ingress controller to do the redirect.  I'm not even sure it can be done, but I figured someone here would know.